# Read flowdiagram as sequential text in R

Tags: r, dplyr, pdftools

I have a flowdiagram as a PDF. I want to extract the text as sequential array/vector in R. Is there an efficient way to do this?

As an example

[image]

I am looking at whether we can have a vector

```
1. Start App
2. Speech Input
3. HTTP POSt Request
..
...
```

Comment: You are trying to perform a complicated [OCR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_character_recognition) from an image (within a PDF) with positioning or even directioning. You can take a look at [tesseract](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tesseract/vignettes/intro.html) but this might be quite a difficult task. Please note that `dplyr`, which you added as tag, is absolutely not related to this kind of things.